# Detecting when I should Use Energy Saving Techniques in Html/Javascript Game

Tags: javascript, mobile, tablet, battery

I have a game written in javascript. I can vary the frame rate and the number of pixels in the main screen depending on whether the user's device is plugged into the mains or is on a battery. I need to preserve battery consumption when there is a battery.

However, how do I check whether it is on a battery? Or is there another way of determining something I can check, such as mobile/tablet status?

Please note, research here on Stackoverflow has already ruled out the battery API, as it does not work on most browsers, as the technology has been depricated. ([Old Tech](https://www.w3.org/TR/battery-status/))

Comment: David Walsh didn't write the battery API, he wrote an article about it.

Comment: Sorry - updating question now